# iFrame procees in Server Side

Tags: php, iframe, server-side

I need a solution for following scenario.

I have a web site hosted in private LAN which is not connected to the internet. I have a web server in different Zone which has connectivity between LAN server and internet. Due to restriction i can not open my LAN to internet or host the website in any other zone.

So i want to create a web page which could host at DMZ, where the web page talk to my internal server and output to be proceed to end user. (Same concept of iFrame) , I believe that iFrame work at client end, not the server end. (Correct me if I'm wrong) .

Does anyone have any idea to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with `<iframe>`. An iframe is nothing more than a call within another page. What you want is far beyond a simple iframe. I just can not understand how its structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to create is called a proxy. An iframe is often used as a proxy to another site's content, but the problem you've run into is that browsers have to have access to the server at the iframe's declared URL. Since it's behind a firewall, as you've mentioned, a server side solution is the only way to go.

Check out Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) or nginx's [proxy capability](http://ef.gy/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server) to handle requests on the server side. They both require root privileges to modify http server configuration.